# Establishing connection with local SQL Server database file

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, connection-string

I am trying to set up connection with a SQL Server database file `AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Data.mdf` located on my D drive.

I have used connection string :

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;"
```

However, I cannot establish connection.

I aim to retrieve the number of employees in a particular department from the database (tables employee and department are present in the db).

Can anyone highlight or suggest steps that would allow me do that?

Comment: The user instance feature is deprecated - you should try to avoid it. Can't you attach the `.mdf` file to a running SQL Server instance and connect to it using it's logical database name, instead of fiddling around with physical .MDF file names??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the sample DataBase from your Sql Server Management Studio, then i will not work. Close your Sql Management Studio if you are working..

Answer (score 0):

Add the mdf file to a new folder in d:\ and try this:
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=d:\data\Customers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
May be there is a problem reading the path.

Answer (score 0):

use following code to connect:

```
public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                string connectString =
                    "Server=IRIS-CSG-108\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                    "Integrated Security=true";
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder =
                    new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);
                Console.WriteLine("Original: " + builder.ConnectionString);
                Console.WriteLine("AttachDBFileName={0}", builder.AttachDBFilename);

                builder.AttachDBFilename = @"E:\\TCMS.mdf";
                Console.WriteLine("Modified: " + builder.ConnectionString);

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    // Now use the open connection.
                    Console.WriteLine("Database = " + connection.Database);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from mytable", connection);
                    da.Fill(ds);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to finish.");
                Console.ReadLine();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```